# Different logger levels for different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In my java days I used to configure the logger so that different classes had different levels i.e.

```
Person.logger.level = :debug
Address.logger.level = :error
```

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with the ruby logger. Perhaps I need to create a separate logger for each class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have luck with a lightweight approach known as log tagging.  The inflexibility of standard logging packages has led me to develop and release Tagalog, which is a single-file,  open-source logging system.  There are versions of the library in PHP, Python, and Ruby available on github:

https://github.com/dorkitude/tagalog

or, specifically for the Ruby version:

https://github.com/dorkitude/tagalog.rb

A simple way to use it in your case is:

```
class Person
  def self.log(input):
    return Tagalog::log(input, [:person, :debug])

# ... (rest of class)

end
```

The advantages of tagging over levels are that you can turn tags on and off as you see fit, and they can be feature-specific, or they can just be levels like you're used to.

Comment: I like the tagging approach a lot, will take a look.

Comment: @opsb - any luck with tagging?  It saves me something like 10% of my development time :)

Comment: yeah I had a play, works very nicely. I think it would work well as a decorator over the standard logger. That way you can plugin into any existing logging infrastructure but with the extra tagging functionality.

Comment: Awesome, I'll have a go at that!